# Unable to use Rails due to unverified SSL certifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I don't have any experience programming and I'm trying to learn Ruby as my first language.

I followed the instructions at http://installrails.com/, used RailsInstaller, and updated gems. My problem comes when I try to create a new application. My terminal tries to run bundle install and I get a message the SSL certifications could not be verified.

I tried numerous solutions for this problem but they do not work. I went to http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html
which told me that one workaround was to save cacerts.pem in my Rails folder and make ruby aware of it. Still didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a common problem for those on Windows (as a different guide seemed to imply?) Any solution for this?

EDIT: According to this guide, you can obtain the new trust certificate and the guide tells you where to put it. It hasn't solved my issue yet, but it seems to work for some others.
http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Comment: What version of Windows are you using and when was it last patched?

Comment: You might want to consider dual booting Ubuntu instead. You will be significantly less likely to experience unusual errors that aren't well documented.

Comment: Windows 10. And it was updated earlier this month.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows10. You can change the default gem source url. In your Gemfile you should add a http url:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org/'
#source 'https://rubygems.org' - not working on windows10
```

it helps - but it's rather a workaround, not a solution :)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. Is there a similar workaround for starting a server with "$ rails server"? That command still doesn't work for me.